# How to give image to a pushpin dynamically in c#

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, bing-maps, pushpin

I have a scenario where I would like the user to view multiple pushpins in Bing maps in a wp7 app. I used maplayer to make the cluster of pushpins, but I could not add an image to that pushpin dynamically in the cs file itself. By the way, I have not used the pushpin control in xaml. I'm just adding the pushpin object to the maplayer while looping through.

Here is my code:

```
maplayer layer = new maplayer();

watcher.start();

for (int i = 0; i < lst.count; i++)

           {                  
                    Pushpin mypin = new Pushpin();
                    watcher.Position.Location.Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(lst[i].Latitude);
                    watcher.Position.Location.Longitude=Convert.ToDouble(lst[i].Longitude);

                }


                GeoCoordinate geo = new GeoCoordinate(watcher.Position.Location.Latitude, watcher.Position.Location.Longitude);
                mypin.Location = geo;

                mypin.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
                mypin.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
                mypin.Content = "My location";
                layer.AddChild(mypin, mypin.Location);
            }
            map1.SetView(watcher.Position.Location, Status == true ? 5.0 : 3.0);
            map1.Children.Add(layer);


watcher.stop();
```

I have also tried using the image brush property to provide image source to pushpin but the pushpin itself goes invisible.

like this:

```
ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush();

ib.ImageSource = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images/push.png", UriKind.Relative));

mypin.Background = ib;
```

Please help me on this. I need this to be done without changing/adding datatemplate to pushpin from the xaml side.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is covered in MSDN, on the page for [Working With Pushpins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg588383%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). Here is the example given, where images are added directly to a layer on the map:

```
namespace WindowsPhoneApplication1
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        MapLayer imageLayer;


        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Create a layer to contain the pushpin images.
            imageLayer = new MapLayer();
            map1.Children.Add(imageLayer);
        }


        private GeoCoordinate mapCenter;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            // Retrieve the center of the current map view.
            mapCenter = map1.Center;

            // Define the image to use as the pushpin icon.
            Image pinImage = new Image();

            //Define the URI location of the image.
            pinImage.Source = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri("bluepushpin.png", UriKind.Relative));

            //Define the image display properties.
            pinImage.Opacity = 0.8;
            pinImage.Stretch = System.Windows.Media.Stretch.None;

            // Put the image at the center of the view.
            PositionOrigin position = PositionOrigin.Center;
            imageLayer.AddChild(pinImage, mapCenter, position);

        }
    }
}
```